# Percentage column in a Pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

[/edit]Solved it, just right click on a field, Pivot table options, used For error message show: "0".

Again 1 step closer, looks like the filters don't work with the IF statement, when I only use the formula ([A]-[B])/[B] it works. How can I add the check if [B] <> 0 ? Do I need to use CALCULATE and what would the code look like?

Ok, found another way of doing it, with the following issues: 
When I use a calculated field with formula =IF([Sum of B]=0;0; ([Sum of A]-[Sum of B])/[Sum of B]) my filters don't work correctly anymore. It empties all fields which are filtered out but doesn't collapse the table. So for example when I filter on 2017, both 2017 and 2018 are displayed but 2018 has only empty fields.

Im kinda new in the whole Pivot Tabel making and I have an issue I can't solve. 
I have 2 columns (A and B) with values, I want to add a 3rd one (let's call it C) with the percentage change per row.

I made the following formula =IF([A]=0;0;[A]/[B]*100-100) which works in the Power Pivot window (Data view) from Excel 2010.
When I add this to my Pivot table (under Σ Values) I can only select Sum, Min, Max, Count, etc. but not the raw output from my column in the designer.

I want the 3 columns to be arranged next to each other and grouped by date so the output looks like 01.2017 A B C 02.2017 A B C so i put date and Σvalues in Column labels and A B and C in Σ values. All 3 get SUM of but C I want the raw data.
How to acclompish this? My colleague (not much better than me in Power Pivot) says I have to make a calculated column in the tabel but I can't find how to do this and can't find it online.

Found something more:
What I get when I right click Edit measure in the PP field list:
[image]

What I would like to see:
[image]

Comment: I think calculated field is not usable for me since : 
- Sum is the only function available for a calculated field.(source: MS)

Comment: Do you have a picture or something to help us understand your issue? Like, what your data looks like and how would you like it to be after adding everything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Calendar table and use the Time Intelligence functions. There's plenty of examples on Google if you search "Calendar", "Time Intelligence", "Year on Year" and the like. I'd suggest you subscribe to Matt Allington's blog, and also check out this specific post:  https://exceleratorbi.com.au/power-pivot-calendar-tables/

Matt has a fantastic book, and if I had one suggestion about picking up PowerPivot it's this: Don't try to muddle through. Buy a book from a pro like Matt or Rob Collie at PowerPivotPro. The cost of a great book is a fraction of the cost of the time you'll otherwise spend scratching your head.

Also check out Mike Girvin's ExcelIsFun YouTube channel for posts on the subject.